# Filter Object property based on array with order of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e'];
```

The API sends this data

```
const data ={a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', e:'e', f:'f'}
```

sometimes the keys are missing as well but the array keys should always be present in the final result.

the output should be `{a:'a', b:'b', d:'', c:'c', e:'e'}`. Please help me with ES6 and give me an explanation. I am using reactjs16.9.
In this given case the object d is missing hence it should be initialised with "".
In case If all the keys exist then extra keys from API should be removed.

Comment: Object keys are not ordered

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I have to extract the values into an array which should come as per the array if the object is not ordered I cant do that.

Comment: @mplungjan I did my research then only decided to ask the question. The actual code is copyrighted hence had to form an example for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

Using || to use space if no entry available

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e'];
const data = {a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', e:'e', f:'f'};

let newObj = {};
let newArr = [];
arr.forEach(item => {
  newObj[item] = data[item] || " ";
  newArr.push(   data[item] || " ");
})
console.log(newObj);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the keys and build a new object by using only wanted keys.

Inside of the callback for mapping, the existence of the key is checked with the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is used for getting either the value from the object or a placeholder `' '` for unknown properties.

The result is either an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) or a simple array.

```js
const
    keys = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e'],
    data = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', e: 'e', f: 'f' },
    result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, k in data ? data[k] : ' '])),
    onlyValues = keys.map(k => k in data ? data[k] : ' ');

console.log(result);
console.log(onlyValues);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What if the d key doesn't exist It should take " " and add that key from that array. The need for ordered result is because the values are to be extracted in the order of array.

Comment: what if I wanted to extract only the values from the final object as an array?

Comment: why not take an array for it? if you still like to use an object, take `Object.values(result)`.

Comment: can you please add an explanation for your answer? So that they could reference your answer for future as well?

Comment: I did @mplungjan but Nina has got it all bang on. I understand her answer Its for others as well. You should also add explanation in the answer.